# execute a multi line shell comand in PHP

Tags: php, powershell, shell

I'm trying to get user email of current user using command line.
In Powershell i paste these lines and it works

```
>> $searcher = [ADSISearcher] "(sAMAccountName=$env:USERNAME)"
>> $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("mail"))
>> $searcher.FindOne().Properties["mail"][0]
test@gmail.com
```

but when i try to do this in php with exec or shell_exec

```
$cmd=<<<CMD
$searcher = [ADSISearcher] "(sAMAccountName=$env:USERNAME)" \
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("mail")) \
$searcher.FindOne().Properties["mail"][0]
CMD;

print_r(shell_exec($cmd));
```

it shows me errors undefined variable searcher

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) instead of [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Just enclose `CMD` in single quotes and PHP will not try to expand your `$searcher` as a PHP variable.

Comment: the error has disappeared but it shows me nothing as a result

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, but it looks like you should remove the back slashes at the end of the first two commands.